# C# conexion con Acces report wiewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer, ms-access

Me sale este error, el problema esta en que me busca una línea de enlace larga y eso me lo genera el `Report Viewer`, hay alguna me
`Excepción` no controlada del tipo`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` en `System.Data.dll`

> Información adicional:
>   'C:\Proyectos\SigaAsistencia\ConexionAccessCSharp\bin\Debug\bin\Debug\bin\Debug\bin\Debug\SigaAsistencia.accdb'
>   is not a valid path.  Make sure that the path name is spelled
>   correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file
>   resides.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado que efectivamente tu base de datos exista en esta ubicación `C:\Proyectos\SigaAsistencia\ConexionAccessCSharp\bin\Debug\bin\Debug\bin\Debug\bin\Debug\`? parece muy raro que apunte dos veces a **Bin\Debug**...Si encontraste la solución, no dudes en publicarla.

Comment: puedes colocar como tienes la cadena de conexion?